# File sharing problem with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu-9.10

I fall in big trouble, I use before Ubuntu and win xp in different 2 desktops, they have no samba related problem. But this time I cannot access from ubuntu to windows 7 or reverse way both..Installed Samba,configure it, searchin web lot and drop some hair from my head...nothin is working...is there any particular solutions on this issue??...I need a descriptive reply on it if u can...my windows 7 is Home Premium edition.

Waiting for your reply guy. Btw, the error shows "Failed to mount windows share" abt ubuntu to w7 and from w7 to ubuntu the error is "find no network path"...both machine is pinging each other...I assure you all r alright but where is the flaws ???

Comment: not a programming related question, see FAQ. I guess you'ld have more luck on a ubuntu forum, or on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 requires NTLM 2.0 Auth by default, which Samba doesn't support. There's an easy registry hack to fix this:

- Click start
- Type: regedit
- Press enter
- In the left, expand these folders:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\
- In the left, click on the folder named: Lsa
- In the right, double-click "LmCompatibilityLevel"
- Type the number 1 and press enter
- Restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Linux expert but I found this. I hope this can help you:

> Ubuntu and Gnome make it easy to access files on a Windows network share. Open the Places Menu, then click on Network. You will see a Windows network icon. Double-click to open it. The next window shows all the domains/workgroups found on your network. Inside each domain/workgroup you will see all the computers on the domain/workgroup with sharing enabled. Double-click on a computer icon to access its shares and files.
>
> If you want to be able to share folders with nautilus (the file browser), install the nautilus-share package (installed by default in Ubuntu 9.10 Desktop edition):
>
> > *sudo apt-get install nautilus-shareAlternate: From the menu at the top*
>
> select "Location" -> "Connect to a server". In the "Service type" pull down select "Windows share". Enter the server ip address in the "Server:" box and the share name in the "Share:" box. Click "Connect" and then "Connect" again on the second dialog box
>
> > Note: The default installation of Samba does not synchronize passwords. You may have to run "smbpasswd" for each user that needs to have access to his Ubuntu home directory from Microsoft Windows.

Windows Clients (XP,Server,Vista, Win7)
Microsoft Windows clients connect and browse through their corresponding network interface.

**Example:** XP clients can open Windows Network Neighborhood or My Network Places to browse available SMB shares.

Well, I can't test it out but I hope this will work for you!